# Django models - searching "backward" ForeignKeys with and'd Q's

Tags: python, django

I have some models that are laid out like so (with a lot more fields):

```
class A(models.Model):
    name = models.
class B(models.Model):
    foo = models.ForeignKey(A)
```

and I have a search system that uses `Q` objects; `0` and `1` are primary keys, obtained by a `ModelMultipleChoiceField` in a form, and both of their `foo`s point to the same `A`.

So for or logic, I can use this

```
>>> A.objects.filter(Q(b__pk=0) | Q(b__pk=1))
[<A: A object>, <A: A object>]
```

and I can fix the duplication by using

```
A.objects.filter(Q(b__pk=0) | Q(b__pk=1)).distinct()
```

However, I also want to do `and` logic. Ideally it would work by using `&` instead of `|`, but that doesn't work.

```
>>> A.objects.filter(Q(b__pk=0) & Q(b__pk=1))
[]
```

So, what is the simplest way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guess you want A instances that having at least one B() w/ primary key 1 and one B() w/ primary key 0

Then you need

```
(A.objects.filter(b__pk=0) & A.objects.filter(b__pk=1)).distinct()
```

Or the following if join hurts

```
A.objects.filter(
    models.Q(pk__in=B.objects.filter(pk=0).values('foo_id')) &
    models.Q(pk__in=B.objects.filter(pk=1).values('foo_id')))
```

If you need A() that having only two relative B() one w/ pk=0 and another pk=1, limitation should be applied to the above queryset by

```
queryset.annotate(b_count=models.Count('b')).filter(b_count=2)
```

Comment: I didn't know that `__and__` for queryset did a join. nice. I'll see if your solutions work later...

Comment: Yup, works perfectly. I used the second one, since I preferred using Q objects, since I do `query = reduce(Q.__and__, queries)`

Answer (score 0):

The best solution that I came up with while investigating my question was this:

```
match_keys = [0,1]
matches = [s for s in A.objects.all() if len(s.b_set.filter(pk__in=match_keys)) == len(match_keys)]
```

However, I'd like to know if there's a better way to do this that just uses `Q` objects, and thus does all of its work within the ORM.